# The current path, 1/password/, didn’t match any of these

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

Im trying to access the reset password through the form link.
Raw passwords are not stored, so there is no way to see this user’s password, but you can change the password using this form.

Traceback

```
Using the URLconf defined in carreview.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
[name='home']
car/<int:pk> [name='post-details']
create_post/ [name='create_post']
car/edit/<int:pk> [name='edit_post']
car/<int:pk>/delete [name='delete_post']
like/<int:pk> [name='likes']
signup/
signup/
The current path, 1/password/, didn’t match any of these.
```

blog/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', view.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('car/<int:pk>', PostDetail.as_view(), name='post-details'),
    path('create_post/', CreatePost.as_view(), name='create_post'),
    path('car/edit/<int:pk>', EditPost.as_view(), name='edit_post'),
    path('car/<int:pk>/delete', DeletePost.as_view(), name='delete_post'),
    path('like/<int:pk>', Likes, name='likes')
]
```

signup/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import UserSignup, ProfileEdit
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views


urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', UserSignup.as_view(), name='register'),
    path('edit_profile/', ProfileEdit.as_view(), name='edit_profile'),
    path('password/', auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view()),
]
```

Edit profile view (signup/views.py)

```
class ProfileEdit(generic.UpdateView):
    form_class = EditProfile
    template_name = 'registration/edit_profile.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user
```

I figured when being redirected its bringing me to:
"gitpod.io/4/password/"
The '4' is actually the User ID, I'm trying to add something in my signup/urls.py so it gets the user id for the path

Comment: Hi, Can you add the link to the password change site? My guess is that you have href"password" instead of href"/password" so it just adds /password to the current url instead of going to domain/password

Comment: @Armin , Im using django password reset. I figured out what is going wrong. When I press the link it redirects me to this 'gitpod.io/4/password/' The '4' is the user ID, Im trying to add the user id into my urls.py right now but can't figure it out.

Comment: the url should be path('<int:pk>/password/', auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view()), and in the view you need to give pk as a parameter.